# Three js light effect not stop by wall , it is overflow the wall

Tags: three.js

I am new to three js, 
In my application i was created point light in a room. Light was overflow the room walls , please look on attached image. 
I need to stop light effect only stay with in a room.

1. I am using MeshPhongMaterial and shapeGeometry for creating mesh for wall
2. In the attached image light was created inside room. I was increased  the distance of point light.it was extended out side of room. This is the problem. I want to stop light using that room walls.

Sample code :

```
[![var shape = new THREE.Shape(),
                    points = getPoints();
                shape.moveTo(points\[0\].x, points\[0\].y);
                for (var i = 1, l = points.length; i < l; i++) {
                    shape.lineTo(points\[i\].x, points\[i\].y)
                }
     var shapeGeometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape);

var wall = new THREE.Mesh(shapeGeometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ 
color: #fffff,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide
                }));
                wall .rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
                wall .position.set(x, y, z);
                scene.add(self._l3d);][1]][1]
```

[image: Light effect image]

Comment: What you are looking for is often called "selective lighting" which is currently not supported in `three.js`. Read this issue for more details about this topic: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5180

Comment: @Mugen87 As I read it, the light source is positioned inside the cube ("room"). Wouldn't this be resolved if Balakrishnan configured the cube to also cast shadows?

Comment: @TheJim01  it is a room with four walls , i just want to stop the light source inside the room using walls, but it was extend the walls and reflect on outside object and causing shadow

Answer (score 2):

Making your room cast shadows will cause it to prevent light from escaping.

In the example below, the diamond is the light. Clicking on the scene will cause the "room" to appear, which encapsulates the light. Because the "room" is configured to cast shadows, the floor doesn't receive the lighting effect.

One thing to note is that both the "room" and the red box are still *lit* by the shadow light. You can set them to receive shadows as well, but that can cause strange effects depending on your shadow map settings. That's just a warning though, and beyond the scope of this question/answer.

```js
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
})
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

const scene = new THREE.Scene()

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(28, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000)
camera.position.set(50, 75, 150)
camera.lookAt(scene.position)

const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1)
light.position.set(0, 0, 1)
camera.add(light)
scene.add(camera)

const aLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.25)
scene.add(aLight)

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

// now for the main scene

const floor = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(100, 100),
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00
  })
)
floor.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2
floor.receiveShadow = true
scene.add(floor)

const shadowLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1)
shadowLight.position.set(-20, 20, -10)
shadowLight.castShadow = true
scene.add(shadowLight)

const slh = new THREE.PointLightHelper(shadowLight, 5)
scene.add(slh)

const outsideBox = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(5, 5, 5),
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000
  })
)
outsideBox.position.set(10, 5, 10)
outsideBox.castShadow = true
scene.add(outsideBox)

const room = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(10, 30, 10),
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0x0000ff
  })
)
room.position.set(-20, 15, -10)
room.castShadow = true
room.visible = false // clicking will toggle visibility
scene.add(room)

render()

renderer.domElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
  room.visible = !room.visible
  render()
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/109/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much jim for your answer, Instead of   var geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape); how can i use boxgeomentry.   My Wall calculations are all in THREE.Shape ,  using this to create Shape geomentry, Instead of this how can i use boz geomentry?

Comment: @BalakrishnanG Shadows aren't defined in the geometry, but are part of the mesh. You should be able to use any type of geometry with your `Mesh` as long as you configure the shadow properties correctly.

Comment: Thanks jim, But i am not able to get your point sorry for that, I am new to three js. can we able to connect on skype or whatsapp? I can show you

Comment: @BalakrishnanG Stack Overflow is a place for shared knowledge, not private tutelage. I recommend you copy my example into your question and modify it to match your use-case. Once you provide a running example (even if it's broken), you'll get better answers.

Comment: @jim, Yes jim, i know that but it is one task give to me,  that application have lost of codes so i am not able to share hole code and also with out that base this part also not work. Any way thanks Jim, I will try other samples also,  Thank you jim